INVALID_SESSION_ID Error when calling apex webservice with Keycloak Integration
We have an Experience cloud which is forwarding Portal Users to an external application. The identity management is done via a keycloak integration. An Apex Webservice is called when a user is logging out of the external application so that the user is automatically logged out from Salesforce as well.
When the Logout webservice is called, the user receives this error:
<Errors>
<Error>
<errorCode>INVALID_SESSION_ID</errorCode>
<message>This session is not valid for use with the REST API</message>
</Error>
</Errors>

I followed the instructions given in this help article but this didn't help.
When debugging the issue, it seems the error happens before the webservice method is executed, as I am not able to get a debug log.
Apex Logout Webservice:
@RestResource(urlMapping='/logout')
global without sharing class LogoutService {
    
    private static String jwtToken;
    private static String state;
    private static String postLogoutURL;
    
    
    @HttpGet
    global static void doGet() {
System.debug('Logout Service Webservice Call');
        
        try {
            validateURLParameter();
            
            String userId = extractUserIdFromJWTToken();
            startSFLogout(userId);      
            redirectToPostLogoutURL();
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            RestContext.response.statusCode = 400;
        }
        catch(PlatformEventException e) {
            RestContext.response.statusCode = 500;
            handleInternalLogoutError(e);
        }
    }
    
    
    // PRIVATE METHODS
    private static void validateURLParameter() {
        jwtToken = RestContext.request.params.get('id_token_hint');
        state = RestContext.request.params.get('state');
        postLogoutURL = RestContext.request.params.get('post_logout_redirect_uri');
        
        if(String.isBlank(jwtToken) || String.isBlank(state) || String.isBlank(postLogoutURL)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException('Missing url parameter');
        }
    }
    
    
    private static String extractUserIdFromJWTToken() {
        String idTokenHint = RestContext.request.params.get('id_token_hint');
        Auth.JWT token = Auth.JWTUtil.parseJWTFromStringWithoutValidation(idTokenHint);
        String sub = token.getSub();
        String userId = sub.substringAfterLast('/');
        
        if( !(userId instanceof Id)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException('Invalid UserId format');
        }
        
        return userId;
    }
   
    
    
    private static void startSFLogout(String userId) {
        CommunityLogout__e logoutEvent = new CommunityLogout__e(UserId__c = userId);
        
        Database.SaveResult sr = EventBus.publish(logoutEvent);
        
        if( !sr.isSuccess()) {
            throw new PlatformEventException(sr.getErrors());
        }
    }
    
    
    private static void redirectToPostLogoutURL() {
        String state = RestContext.request.params.get('state');
        String postLogoutURL = RestContext.request.params.get('post_logout_redirect_uri');
        
        RestContext.response.statusCode = 302;
        RestContext.response.addHeader('Location', postLogoutURL + '?state=' + state);
        RestContext.response.addHeader('http-equiv','refresh');
    }
    
    
    private static void handleInternalLogoutError(PlatformEventException internalError) {
        for(Database.Error err : internalError.errors) {
            System.debug('Error publishing platform event: ' + err.getStatusCode() + ' - ' + err.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    
    // CUSTOM EXCEPTION CLASS
    private class PlatformEventException extends Exception {
        public List<Database.Error> errors {get; private set;}
        
        public PlatformEventException(List<Database.Error> errors) {
            this.errors = errors;
        }
    }
}

Platform Event Trigger for internal Logout
trigger LogoutEventTrigger on CommunityLogout__e (after insert) {
  for (CommunityLogout__e event : Trigger.New) {
      if (String.isNotBlank(event.UserId__c)) {
          AuthSession[] currentUserSessions = [SELECT Id FROM AuthSession WHERE UsersId = :event.UserId__c];
          delete currentUserSessions;
      }
  }
}


Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful. Your example is somewhat Minimal, not Complete and therefore not Reproducible.

The issue was the Salesforce cookies. The "sid" cookie stored the Session Id of the logged in Community user. When the keycloak forwarded the User to the Salesforce Webservice which in turn forwarded the user to another url, the Session Id was validated for for API and Endpoint Access and the error occurs. Even though the REST Webservice is publicly available via the Exp. Cloud domain, the session is executed with the Community User Context and fails despite the Community User having correct permissions (Apex REST API & Apex Class Access).
Removing the cookies allowed the Callout to succeed.
